# c++ define variable inside if block for function scope

Tags: c++, variables, scope

Background: I am working on developing several different controllers (over 10 or so) for a hardware which involves running the code in hard real-time under RTAI linux. I have implemented a class for the hardware with each controller as a separate member function of the class. I'm looking to pass the desired trajectory for the respective control variable to each of these control functions based on which controller is chosen. In addition, since there are several parameters for each controller and I am looking to quickly switch controllers without having to navigate through the entire code and changing parameters, I am looking to define all the control variables at one place and define them based on which controller I choose to run. Here is a minimum working example of what I am looking for.

I am looking to define variables based on if a condition is true or not as follows in C++:

```cpp
int foo()
{
  int i=0;

  if(i==0)
  {
    int a=0;
    float b=1;
    double c=10;
  }
  elseif(i==1)
  {
    int e=0;
    float f=1;
    double g=10;
  }

// Memory locked for hard real-time execution
// execute in hard real-time from here

  while(some condition) 
  {
// 100's of lines of code
    if(i==0)
    {
     a=a+1;
     b=b*2;
     c=c*4;
// 100's of lines of code
    }
    elseif(i==1)
    {
     e=e*e*e;
     f=f*3;
     g=g*10;
// 100's of lines of code
    }
// 100's of lines of code
  }   

// stop execution in hard real-time
}
```

The above code gives error on execution as the scope of the variables defined in the if blocks is limited to the respective if block. Could anyone suggest a better way of handling this issue? What is the best practice in this context in C++?

Comment: You really need to go read an intro C++ book on variable scoping and lifetime.

Comment: Declare variables right before use. Problem solved.

Comment: You have to think about why you need to define them inside a if block at first

Comment: You can write the variable definitions like that, but they go out of scope at the following `}`, so you can't write the code that uses the variables (because they are not defined).  In any case, you're trying to combine two different function bodies into a single function.  Use two separate functions, one to process `a`, `b`, and `c`, the other to process `e`, `f` and `g`.  If you must, keep your current function to call the correct other function.

Comment: Not to be snarky, but what do you think `{` and `}` do?

Comment: Looks like you could use two separate functions.

Comment: Please check the updated post. I have 100's of lines of common code inside the for loop which would need to be repeated if I create two different functions. In addition the loop is executing in hard real-time under RTAI Linux, so calling more functions will cost overheads and would degrade the hard real-time performance by increasing jitter.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you may simply use:

```
int foo()
{
    int i = 0;

    if (i == 0) {
        int a = 0;
        float b = 1;
        double c = 10;

        for(int j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
            a = a + 1;
            b = b * 2;
            c = c * 4;
        }
    } else if (i == 1) {
        int e = 0;
        float f = 1;
        double g = 10;
        for(int j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
            e = e * e * e;
            f = f * 3;
            g = g * 10;
        }
    }
}
```

or even better, create sub-functions

```
void foo0()
{
    int a = 0;
    float b = 1;
    double c = 10;

    for(int j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
        a = a + 1;
        b = b * 2;
        c = c * 4;
    }
}

void foo1()
{
    //.. stuff with e, f, g
}

int foo()
{
    int i = 0;

    if (i == 0) {
        foo0();
    } else if (i == 1) {
        foo1();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check the updated post. I have 100's of lines of common code inside the for loop which would need to be repeated if I create two different functions. In addition the loop is executing in hard real-time, so calling more functions will cost overheads and would degrade the hard real-time performance by increasing jitter.

Comment: Compiler may inline functions (better than us) and by grouping case into sub-function, you avoid lot of branches with your `if else if` in your loop.